# Setting Rails Environment for Apache by Environment Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, docker, passenger

I'm using Rails / Apache and Passenger inside a Docker container - is it possible to set the environment variable when running the container via Docker to override this? Here's my abbreviated apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>

       [...]

        <Directory /home/website/app/public>

       [...]

        RailsEnv production

       [...]

        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And here's what I'm using to run my Docker container:

```
$ docker run -e "RACK_ENV=development" -e "RAILS_ENV=development" --rm -p 80:80 --name web-container web
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`PassEnv` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#passenv) should specify one or more native system environment variables to make available as internal environment variables.

You can then use `${RAILS_ENV}` in your `httpd.conf` file.

If you’re running httpd 2.4+, you can turn on **[`mod_info`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_info.html)** and browse to http://servername/server-info?config to dump the current configuration, which will show the variable substitution.